# Slideshow not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, slideshow, lightbox

I have a [slideshow](http://www.galerie.thomasknoell.ch/js/slideshow.js) made with [JQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js)(external), a modified [Mootools](http://www.galerie.thomasknoell.ch/js/mootools.js) and a modified [Lightbox](http://www.galerie.thomasknoell.ch/js/lightbox_slsh.js). It works like a charm on all tested browsers except IE10 (maybe 9 as well).

IE10 gives me the error:

> Script5022: InvalidCharacterError mootools.js, line 15 character 20608

The Mootools file is minified and I have no clue about javascript so it is hopeless for me to fix it. I don't know where to start with it and it's too much code to post here. All of the files are linked above and [here](http://www.galerie.thomasknoell.ch) is the page itself.

Comment: FYI, java and javascript are two completely different programming languages.

Comment: ok, thanks. I never can keep them apart...

Comment: don't use mootools 1.2.1. it predates ie10 by 4-5 years. it fails to feature detect modern browsers correctly. upgrade to 1.4.5 with compat layer and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did it with a simple

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

works fine for me...